# How to Access History Object Outside of a React Component

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

First of all, I am pretty familiar with the [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HoC, however, in this case, it doesn't help because I do not want to access the `history` object in a component.

I am trying to achieve a mechanism that will redirect the user to the login page if I receive back a 401 from a API endpoint. For making http requests I am using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios). I have around 60 endpoints that I need to cover, that are used in a dozen of components throughout my app.

I want to create a decorator function to the axios instance object, that:

```
1. makes the request
2. if fail && error_code = 401, update user route to `/login`
3. if success, return promise
```

The problem I have with the above is to update the route of the user. Previously, in `react-router-v3`, I could have imported the `browserHistory` object directly from the react-router package, which is no longer possible.

So, my question is, how can I access the history object outside of the React Component without passing it trough the call stack?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

react-router v4 also provides a way to share history via the `history` package, namely `createBrowserHistory()` function.

The important part is to make sure that the same history object is shared across your app. To do that you can take advantage of the fact that node modules are singletons.

Create a file called `history.js` in your project, with the following content:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;
```

You can then just import it in your application via:

```
import history from "./history.js";
```

Please note that only `Router` accepts the `history` prop (`BrowserRouter` does not), so be sure to update your router JSX accordingly:

```
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import history from "./history.js";

// and then in your JSX:
return (
  <Router history={history}>
    {/* routes as usuall */}
  </Router>
)
```

A working example can be found at https://codesandbox.io/s/owQ8Wrk3

Comment: In current version, using history and passing it as a prop is resulting with not being able to render component. Basically what happens is, url changes but component is not rendered unless you dont refresh the page.

Comment: @cool make sure you are using Router, not BrowserRouter / HashRouter etc.

Comment: For react-router version 4.2.0, I had to change the ```'history/createBrowserHistory';``` to ```'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';```

Comment: Apart from history object, I need to access match object.

Is it possible to get same outside the component?

Comment: @praveensanap yes, it should work with all router types

Comment: This does not work for me.. components on the routes that I push to the history object don't render

Comment: This wont work in newer version. Any other way to do it. This solution requires reload of page.

Comment: One notice: better to use `createHashHistory` instead of `createBrowserHistory` if it's used for react hash routes.

Answer (score 6):

Today, I faced the same issue. Maybe my solution helps somebody else.

src/axiosAuthenticated.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';


const UNAUTHORIZED = 401;

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => {
    const {status} = error.response;
    if (status === UNAUTHORIZED) {
      createBrowserHistory().push('/');
      window.location.reload();
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
 }
);

export default axios;
```

Also, if you want to intercept any request to add token stored in LocalStorage:

```
let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

var authToken = "";
if (user && user.token)
  authToken = 'Bearer ' + user.token;

axios.defaults.headers.common = {'Authorization': `${authToken}`}
```

To use it, instead of importing from 'axios', import from 'axiosAuthenticated' like this:

```
import axios from 'utils/axiosAuthenticated'
```

Comment: `window.location.reload` was what I needed.  This shouldn't be needed if the same history hooked up to the router component is used here but in React Router 5 it looks like the history property was removed, and it can only be accessed via hooks within a component.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that worked for me in latest version(**5.2.0**)

**router/index.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Routes } from "./routes";

export const Router = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Routes />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

**router/routes.js**

```
import React, { createRef } from "react";
import { Route, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree } from "../pages";

export const historyRef = createRef();

export const Routes = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  historyRef.current = history;

  return (
    <>
      <Route exact path="/" component={PageOne} />
      <Route exact path="/route-one" component={PageTwo} />
      <Route exact path="/route-two" component={PageThree} />
    </>
  );
};
```

**And use it as below**

```
historyRef.current.replace("/route-two");
```

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this same issue, and following is the solution I used to solve this problem.

I ended up creating a factory function which returns an object that has all my services functions. In order to call this factory function, an object with the following shape must be provided.

```
interface History {
    push: (location: string) => void;
}
```

Here is a distilled version of my factory function.

```
const services = {};

function servicesFactory(history: History) {
    const countries = countriesFactory(history);
    const local = {
        ...countries,
    };
    Object.keys(local).forEach(key => {
        services[key] = local[key];
    });

}
```

Now the file where this function is defined exports 2 things.

1)This factory function

2)the services object.

This is what the countries service looks like.

```
function countriesFactory(h: History): CountriesService {
    const countries: CountriesService = {
        getCountries() {
            return request<Countries>({
                method: "get",
                endpoint: "/api/countries",
            }, h)
        }
    }
    return countries;
}
```

And finally here is what my `request` function looks like.

```
function request<T>({ method, endpoint, body }: Request, history: History): Promise<Response<T>> {
    const headers = {
        "token": localStorage.getItem("someToken"),
    };
    const result: Response<T> = {
        data: null,
        error: null,
    };
    return axios({
        url: endpoint,
        method,
        data: body,
        headers,
    }).then(res => {
        result.data = res.data;
        return result;
    }).catch(e => {
        if (e.response.status === 401) {
            localStorage.clear();
            history.push("/login");
            return result;
        } else {
            result.error = e.response.data;
            return result;
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see the `request` function exepcts to have the history object passed to it which it will get from the service, and the service will get it from the services factory.

Now the cool part is that I only ever have to call this factory function and pass the history object to it once in the entire app. After that I can simply import the `services` object and use any method on it without having to worry about passing the history object to it.

Here is the code of where I call the services factory function.

```
const App = (props: RouteComponentProps) => {
  servicesFactory(props.history);
  return (
    // my app and routes
  );
}
```

Hope someone else who finds this question will find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

I am providing my solution here as accepted answer does not address the new versions of React Router and they require reload of the page to make that solution work.

I have used the same BrowserRouter. I have created a class with static functions and a member history instance.

/****history.js***/

```
class History{
   static historyInstance = null;

   static push(page) {
        History.historyInstance.push(page);
   }

}
```

/****app-router.js***/

```
const SetHistoryInstance = () => {
   History.historyInstance = useHistory();
   return (null);
};

const AppRouter = () => {
  
  return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <SetHistoryInstance></SetHistoryInstance>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={'/'} component={Home} />
        <Route path={'/data'} component={Data} exact />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
)};
```

Now you can import history.js anywhere in your app and use it.

Comment: Why the SetHistoryInstance is called as a Fn component, cant we set it directly?

Comment: There are some solutions in this thread where they are setting it directly but it does not work for me. I think BrowserRouter sets its own instance of history which we capture via Fn component.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to `useHistory()` in `App.js` and then use `render` and pass `history` as an attribute of the component:

```js
function App() {
  const history = useHistory();
<Router>
 <Route
 path={nav.multiCategoriesNoTimer}
 render={() => <MultiCategoriesNoTimer history={history} />}
/>
</Router>
}
```

```js
const MixMultiGameNoTimer = (props: any) => {
if (true) {
    return (
      <NoQuestionsHereScreen history={props.history} />
    );
  }
}
```

```js
const NoQuestionsHereScreen = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <div className='no-questions-here' >
      <Button
        title="Go back"
        onClick={() => props.history.push(nav.home)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

There is a bit of drilling, but it works and that for many future versions too>

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution that could solve this issue.
[Access react router dom history object outside React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71611267/access-react-router-dom-history-object-outside-react-component)

I think this approach will work with both React-router v4 and v5.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).