# × history.props.push() getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" even when wrapping component in withRouter()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to user browser routing to render a different component in my app.
Using this tutorial as reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nq9RmAB9eag

When I try to use this.props.history.push('Path I want to go to') I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. The common solution is to wrap the component using withRouter(), but I have done this and I am still getting the error.

I have also tried redirecting to a different path than '/'.

I used the same function in a different component and it works fine.

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
AuthenticatedComponent.render
C:/Users/Liam/Desktop/appFolder/client/src/components/AuthenticatedComponent.js:41
  38 | 
  39 |  render() {
  40 |    console.log(this.state);
> 41 |    this.props.history.push('/');
     | ^  42 |    if (this.state.user === undefined) {
  43 |      return (
  44 |        <div><h1>Loading...</h1></div>
```

Here is the code of the non working component (AuthenticatedComponent.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getJwt } from '../utilities/jwt'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'

export class AuthenticatedComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: undefined
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const jwt = getJwt();
    if (!jwt) {
      // If no JWT token, bring user back to login page (currently root)
      this.props.history.push('/');
    }



    axios.get('api/getUser', { headers: { "auth-token": jwt } }).then((res) => {
      this.setState({user: res.data})

    }
    ).catch(err => {

      console.log("An error occurred getting user: ", err);
      localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
      // Redirect to login
      this.props.history.push('/');
    });


  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    if (this.state.user === undefined) {
      return (
        <div><h1>Loading...</h1></div>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(AuthenticatedComponent);
```

Here is app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { LoginContainer } from './components/LoginForm/LoginContainer';
import { AuthenticatedComponent } from './components/AuthenticatedComponent'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Protected from './components/ProtectedExample'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={LoginContainer} />
          <AuthenticatedComponent>
            <Route path="/Protected" component={Protected} />
          </AuthenticatedComponent>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>

    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could resolve your problem:

```
import React from 'react';
import { LoginContainer } from './components/LoginForm/LoginContainer';
import { AuthenticatedComponent } from './components/AuthenticatedComponent'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Protected from './components/ProtectedExample'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={LoginContainer} />
          <Route 
            path="/Protected" 
            render={props => (
              <AuthenticatedComponent history={props.history}>
                <Protected/>
              </AuthenticatedComponent>
            )}
          />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

---

Another solution is to install the history package in order to access "history" outside Route components.

For more information on the latter, check out this SO answer: [How to Access History Object Outside of a React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153517/how-to-access-history-object-outside-of-a-react-component)

Comment: Could you please explain what you did?

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I'm just curious though, do you know why history.push() worked in a separate component but not the auth component?

Comment: For context it is called in the submit function MainLogin.js, which is returned from LoginContainer.js, which is rendered within app.js.

Comment: @CristianTraìna Sure. It's kinda simple. Components wrapping <Route/> wont get passed the props from react-router, such as "location" or "history". Therefore, in order for AuthenticatedComponent to access those props, it needs to be passed using the "render" prop from "Route".

Comment: @L.O'Shea That is because when you use the "component={LoginContainer}" you are passing all the react-router props into that component. Is the same as declaring it like: "render={props => <LoginContainer {...props}/>}"

Comment: @ubinatus Thanks for your continued insight. I think I understand. I had called the protected component like that: <Route path="/Protected" component={Protected} /> ... but I did not call the Authenticated component like that, which is where I needed the history. Does passing the History to a parent component make it accessible in the child components without further changes to the code?

Comment: @L.O'Shea Yes, as long as you pass the history prop to the child.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the browser router with history,

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

...

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

return   <BrowserRouter history={browserHistory}> 
...
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I tried this but got the same error:

`
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

class App extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

    return (
      <BrowserRouter history = {this.browserHistory}>
        <Switch>
          <AuthenticatedComponent>
            <Route path="/Protected" component={Protected} />
          </AuthenticatedComponent>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
`

Sorry the code markdown doesn't seem to be working