# How to access the "history" object in non component files in react while using BrowserRouter?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am using react hooks and redux. I have wrapped the `App` component with `BrowserRouter`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and in the `App` component, I am using `useHistory` hook to get the `history` object:

```
const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(()=>{
    history.listen((location, action) => {
      // clear alert on location change
      dispatch(alertActions.clear());
    });
```

But i want to access the `history` object in my **action creator file** used for login, so that i can do this after login:

```
history.push('/');
```

How do I achieve this? do I have to use `Router` instead of `BrowserRouter`?

Edit:
I had to use `Router`, instead of `BrowserRouter`, and it is working now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Access History Object Outside of a React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153517/how-to-access-history-object-outside-of-a-react-component)

Comment: In  your link , the accepted answer suggests using 'Router' , i have already tried that approach and i was facing some issues with routes, so i decided to use BrowserRouter, so there is no way this can be done with BrowserRouter?

Comment: using Router and passing your own history object should be the way to achieve this, what issues were you encountering using Router instead of BrowserRouter? BrowserRouter just obfuscates creating the history object: [https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/BrowserRouter.js](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/BrowserRouter.js)

Comment: @JacobSmit  can i use the useHistory hook with Router?

Comment: Yes. `react-router` has it's own implementation of `useHistory()`, I assume `react-router-dom` re-exports the same hook.

Comment: `connected-react-router` https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router