# Access History object outside React component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have gone through all the StackOverflow answers to get history instance outside of react component. Am currently using window.location to route outside the react component. which causing app refresh. I would like to use history instance in the below file

Options Tried:

[How to Access History Object Outside of a React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153517/how-to-access-history-object-outside-of-a-react-component)

Which causing location prop from withRouter (or) useLocation() undefined

**AuthService.ts**

```
logout() {
if (!isEmpty(localStorage.getItem("authToken"))) {
  remove("user/logout").then(() => {
    if (window.location.pathname !== "/auth/login") {
      localStorage.removeItem("authToken");
      window.location.pathname("/auth/login");
    }
  });
}
```

}

ApiService.ts

```
const handleError = (err: AxiosError) => {
  if (
    err.response?.status === 401 &&
    window.location.pathname !== "/auth/login"
  ) {
    window.location.pathname = "/auth/login";
  }
  captureException(err);

  return {
    message:
      (err.response && err.response.data.message) ||
      err.toString().split(":")[1] ||
      "Something Went Wrong",
  };
};
```

Comment: if you want to navigate to the `/auth/login` url, why are you not using `window.history.pushState({}, document.title, /auth/login);` ?

Comment: You can simply store a reference of the “navigation” object and use it from a service or so.

Comment: Hi. I created a solution that could solve this issue. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71611267/access-react-router-dom-history-object-outside-react-component. I think this approach will work with both React-router v4 and v5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router)

You need to connect it with redux.

```
// reducers.js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router'

const createRootReducer = (history) => combineReducers({
  router: connectRouter(history),
  ... // rest of your reducers
})
export default createRootReducer
```

Comment: This is good only if you are using Redux. Integrating Redux to solve this problem is an overkill in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, it works cool. But Router state is showing undefined all the time