# Access react router dom history object outside React component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am looking for a good way to use the history object of `react-router-dom` anywhere in the app. No matter it's a react component or not.

The solution I thought might be good was using the `window` object.

in App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { getUser } from "./axios";

const App = () => {
  let history = useHistory();

  if (!window.reactHistory) {
    window.reactHistory = history;
  // attach history object to window object. 
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

in Index.js nothing too fancy,

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

In api.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getUser = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("");

    if (res.status === 401) {
      if (window.reactHistory) {
        console.log("reactHistory :", window.reactHistory);
        window.reactHistory.push("/login");
        // access react-router-dom history via window object
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {}
};
```

Used react-router-dom version is `5.3.0`.
You can find the code above in my codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-yonath-o13kcq?file=/src/App.js

I tested this approach and it's worked well so far.
But no one seems to use the history object this way and I wondered whether it's a really good way.

I'd appreciate it if you give your opinion.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd create a history object using `createBrowserHistory` (*or the matching variant for the router you use*) and pass this to the low level router. Import the created history object where needed.

See [`Router`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/core/api/Router)

> The common low-level interface for all router components. Typically
> apps will use one of the high-level routers instead:
>
> - `<BrowserRouter>`
> - `<HashRouter>`
> - `<MemoryRouter>`
> - `<NativeRouter>`
> - `<StaticRouter>`
>
> The most common use-case for using the low-level  is to
> synchronize a custom history with a state management lib like Redux or
> Mobx. Note that this is not required to use state management libs
> alongside React Router, it’s only for deep integration.

> ```
> import React from "react";
> import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
> import { Router } from "react-router";
> import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
>
> const history = createBrowserHistory();
>
> ReactDOM.render(
>   <Router history={history}>
>     <App />
>   </Router>,
>   node
> );
> ```

Since you are using `react-router-dom@5` then ensure you have installed `history@4` version. The latest `history@5` version works with `react-router-dom@6` version until v6.4 when the Data APIs were introduced.

- Create and export a history object.

  ```
    import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

    export default createBrowserHistory();
  ```
- import your history object and instantiate the router.

  ```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import { Router } from "react-router";
    import history from "../path/to/history";

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Router history={history}>
        <App />
      </Router>,
      node
    );
  ```
- import your history object in `api.js`.

  ```
    import axios from "axios";
    import history from "../path/to/history";

    export const getUser = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("....");

        if (res.status === 401) {
          history.push("/login");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        ....
      }
    };
  ```

For more details creating custom history objects see [basic usage](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/v4/docs/GettingStarted.md#basic-usage).

Answer (score 0):

In React Router v6 this has now been addressed. By creating a `router` via your preferred strategy (`createBrowserRouter` is recommended), you'd pass that `router` to a `<RouterProvider>` component - thus your history is created and maintained in RR's internals.

```js
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: "*", element: <Index /> }
])

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

You can use that `router` later in a similar way as you would use the old `history` object, like so:

```js
import router from `App`;

// Code outside of the React tree
function (route) {
  router.navigate(route);
}
```

- [createBrowserRouter docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router)
- [RouterProvider docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/router-provider)